# SQL::Maker how to add functions to fields

Tags: sql, perl

MWE:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use SQL::Maker;

our $builder = SQL::Maker->new(
    driver => 'mysql',
);

my @fields = (
    ['ABS(field)'  => 'VAT'],
);

my ($sql, @bind) = $builder->select("test", \@fields);
print $sql;
```

Output:

```
SELECT `ABS(field)` AS `VAT`
FROM `test`
```

How can I get:

```
SELECT ABS(`field`) AS `VAT`
FROM `test`
```

?

Comment: Doesn't seem like the module supports functions. Maybe write your own postprosessing method or consider asking for a new feature [at the issue tracker](https://github.com/tokuhirom/SQL-Maker/issues)

Comment: @HåkonHægland I added the issue to github. But as it seems to me, the module is abandoned as the last issues are hanging from 2012 and a pull request from 2013. Maybe, doing my own fork and writing the feature is an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the verbatim code, we need to quote the field name:

```
my @fields = (
    [\'ABS(field)'  => 'VAT'],
);
```

Output:

```
SELECT ABS(field) AS `VAT`
FROM `test`
```

Answer (score 1):

the following may or may not work, `quote_char` sometimes can be omitted, but the risks being introduced are up to you to evaluate:

```perl
our $builder = SQL::Maker->new(
    driver => 'MySQL',
    quote_char => '',
);
```

and later

```perl
my @fields = (
    ['ABS(`field`)'  => 'VAT'],
);
```

this gives:

```sql
SELECT ABS(`field`) AS VAT
FROM test
```

Comment: or just write your own plain old SQL, since you already know the desired statement